# Error 404 Message | Django | PyCharm

Tags: windows, port, django

Right, is there any particular valid reason as to why - despite me doing everything correctly - do I get the error 404 message when I deploy my development server (on port 8000) from PyCharm?

This is the tutorial I am following [Youtube Tutorial](https://youtu.be/_uQrJ0TkZlc?si=7I-EvqOAegj4kQt3&t=18102) which I have followed to the letter. Why does it work for him and not for me?

I have confirmation the services has started. I have started this y using the following command

`python manage.py runserver`

Why is is that when setting my URL paths in the `/urls` config file on Django framework, does the browser just decide not to bother to actually read the file?

- I have tried changing the port number in the settings on the PyCharm app - but what would have been way too simple.
- I have tried closing down the app then starting it back up - of course that didn't work because that would have made my life way too easy
- I've tried Googling the problem, it suggested the above

Here is my code below, first first snippet is apparently where the problem lies according to the browser. They're in separate files:

```
#Filename: pyshop/urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('products/', include('products.urls'))
]

from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index)
]

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
return HttpResponse('Hello World')
```

You will see its not my code. So what is it?  And how do I get rid of the 404 problem?

[Error 404 message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXJ2P.png)

Comment: Are you using some type of plugin with Django?  That plugin might be the problem, because it looks like *that* is handling things - `pyshop/urls.py` sounds like it's a predefined plugin, etc. and Django is not set properly with actual URLs or is being taken over by this plugin.

Comment: The only plugin is the installation of Dhango 4.2 - that is a file I created.

Comment: Re you edit: Did you maybe add a file with an additional URL specification, but did not configure Django to actually load that applications URLs? It is unclear what is which file, and why you believe both are consulted for paths at the same level.

Answer (score 1):

The URL `http://example.com/` (that is an empty path!) matches neither the prefix `admin/` nor the prefix `admin/`.

Append either prefix to the URL you are attempting to open (e.g. try openinig `http://example.com/admin/`), or add a new entry in your urlpatterns about where the empty URL should point/redirect to.

Comment: @Hunktydunkaty nuke browser cache?  Usually caching is a problem on browsers.

Comment: @anx that is exactly what I have done.